# PHP replace text in a <div>, if it's needed to be changed

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to replace the text with PHP in a div,

> 18 West Main Street

Though I needed it to be changed if the text is `19 West Main Street`. If it's that, it would be changed to something else. I've tried doing this with an array, but have had no luck.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php, though I can't find a way to do this with an if statement and including the changed text from a div tag.

Comment: More code and context please. Where is this being replaced? A div exists on a page, not on  a server. Are you trying to replace on a browser (you've tagged javascript and HTML) or in a string (you've tagged PHP)?

Comment: If its a string base, try str_replace() http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Try http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the follwing should get you started:

```
<?php
$html = '<div>19 West Main Street</div><div>18 West Main Street</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xPath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xPath->query("//div[text() = '18 West Main Street']|//div[text() = '19 West Main Street']");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeValue == '18 West Main Street') {
        $node->nodeValue = 'Something';
    } else {
        $node->nodeValue = 'something else';
    }
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/V4ZMPT

It finds all `div`s with the text `19 / 18 West Main Street` and replaces it with "something (else)". If that is not what you want I don't understand your question entirely :)

Or if you only want to replace the text `19 West Main Street` you could do:

```
<?php
$html = '<div>19 West Main Street</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xPath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xPath->query("//div[text() = '19 West Main Street']");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue = 'something else';
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/HeLk5i

Answer (score 0):

I have done this, and it works well :)

below link shows the working example

    `{
    http://jsfiddle.net/SagarPPanchal/u225F/1/
    }`

Thank You

Exactly i don't know how to write link in a proper way here, so I am sorry for this

```
<div id="example2div" style="border-style:solid; padding:20px;">Replace me with something, please.</div>
    <textarea cols="36" rows="4" name="new" style="width:350px;" onchange="EffectReplacement(this)" wrap="on"></textarea>
    <select onchange="" id="s_box" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <option value="TEST_ONE">TEST_ONE</option>
        <option value="TEST_TWO">TEST_TWO</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Change Content" style="width:350px;" onclick="return show_stuff();">
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Hide Content" style="width:350px;" onclick="return hide_stuff();">



<script>
 function ReplaceContentInContainer(id, content) {
     var container = document.getElementById(id);
     container.innerHTML = content;
 }

 function EffectReplacement(it) {
     re = /script/ig;
     var content = it.value.replace(re, 's.c.r.i.p.t');
     ReplaceContentInContainer('example2div', content);
 }

 function show_stuff() {
     document.getElementById('s_box').style.visibility = "Visible";
 }

 function hide_stuff() {
     document.getElementById('s_box').style.visibility = "hidden";
 }
</script>
```